# \n or \t not working in C# String stored in SQL-Server database

Tags: sql-server, string, crystal-reports, textfield

I am fetching a string by using some custom method `GetGUIString()` from `sql database,` the string is something like this:

```
"my first statement \n my second statement \n my third statement \t"
```

I assigned that string to `Itextobject` in crystal report, but I am seeing that `\n` or `\t` has no Impact. I even tried `<br>` or `<br />` but no success.

I can see the string in debug mode exactly as it shown above.

But interesting thing is, when I hard coded the above string in some string variable and assign to `Itextobject`, I can see the impact

whats wrong?

Comment: in crystal report there is property to load html as text

Comment: I am using crystal report 11, where i can find this property?

Comment: where you bind report control there in formatting option in which you can find, now a days i am not use crystal report so not memorise

Comment: normally when you use crystal report formula then go to format options and in 3rd tab you have option to use `text interpretation` there change to html